# How do I populate an array inside a model with properties of the model?

Tags: angularjs

I have no idea if i'm phrasing the question properly so I apologize for the wording.

I am trying to populate the users array with whatever is in region. So for this example, I would like users to have ['test', 'sean', 'rocky', john'] inside of it.

```
function exController($scope, stvermService) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.model = {
            region: "Test",
            users: [region, 'sean', 'rocky', 'john']
        }; 
}
```

However, that does not work but gives me an error stating that region is undefined. I have also tried model.region and vm.model.region instead of region.

Comment: I don't see any `region` variable in your code

Comment: It should be vm.model.region

Comment: as @Vivz said, it should be: `users: [vm.model.region, 'sean', 'rocky', 'john']`

Comment: Ah so apparently when region is set to region: "" that does not work which was initially confusing me. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JS function as a constructor:

```js
function ExampleModel(region, users) {
  this.model = {
    region: region,
    users: [region].concat(users)
  }
}
    
var vm = {};
vm.model = new ExampleModel("Test", ['sean', 'rocky', 'john']).model;
console.log(vm.model);
```

Using `vm.model.region` **does not work**. Not sure why the comments are pushing that as a solution.

```js
var vm = {};
vm.model = {
  region: "Test",
  users: [vm.model.region, 'sean', 'rocky', 'john']
}; 
console.log(vm.model);
```